# XAMPP access forbidden issues

Tags: php, apache, xampp, laravel-5, http-status-code-403

Having issues with XAMPP and access forbidden problems.

Started using laravel, complete noob to anything MVC but thought I'd give it a go.

Started having issues with page routing, index page works fine, yet non of my routes work, all come up with a 404 error.

Have a little search around the internet, find out it could be due to my xampp/Apache config.

Had a play with the

```
Allow from all
```

and

```
Require all granted
```

options, but no dice.

This is my vhosts entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Projects\xxx\Website-3.0\Website\public"
    ServerName gw3.dev
    <Directory "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Projects\xxx\Website-3.0\Website\public">
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is what I edited in the httpd.conf file.

```
<Directory />
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Made sure that the root directory is not read only.
Yet all I get are 403 - forbidden access errors.

Running Windows 10, fyi.

Not really sure where I'm going wrong here. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: try to put the folder on the drive D could be the permission problem accessing drive C

Comment: Add `AllowOverride All` to the vhosts entry and make sure you restart/reload Apache to pick up the new setting.

Comment: @volkinc It is almost never a permission issue on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section

```
<Directory />
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Provides the basic security for the disk that Apache is installed on. Basic practice is deny access to everything and then allow access to only those directories that Apache should have access to. Also you are using Pache 2.2. and 2.4 syntax together, bad.

So change that back to :-

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

In the definition of the virtual host you are using both Apache 2.2 and 2.4 syntax. Thats not a good idea it can cause Apache to get confused. Also you are using the DOS back slash and that should be the unix forward slash.

So try this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Projects/xxx/Website-3.0/Website/public"
    ServerName gw3.dev
    <Directory "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Projects/xxx/Website-3.0/Website/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you dont actually intend to allow anybody in the universe to access this site then you can use

```
Require local
```

Or if you want to access the site from another device in your local network you could try

```
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Note use of only 3 of the 4 quartiles of the IPV4 ip address. This allows access from any ip in that subnet.

Also make sure that you have added `gw3.dev` to your HOSTS file for both IPV4 and IPV6 addresses

```
127.0.0.1 gw3.dev
::1  gw3.dev
```

Retart Apache and try that.

Comment: Changing my httpd.conf and my vhosts to what you supplied worked, thank you. Must of been some misconfiguration with copying stuff from the internet.

Comment: Love to know why this got a tick and a downvote? I guess I have upset somebody with a vindictive nature

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
 AllowOverride All
```

too in vhost

also dont forget to reboot the server